# List file name patterns and residing directories

Tags: osx-mavericks, dir

Using Mac OS X Mavericks, how do I find file name patterns residing in different, unknown, directories (ie: would be equivalent of Windows/DOS command:  `dir /b \x*.y*`) ?

Comment: [`man find`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using [find(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html):

```
find /path/to/directory -name \*.y\* -print
```